# i have a input text want same formatting in output text in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have 1 input text and 1 output text. output text shows the same text as in input text with some highlighted words. But i want to maintain the formatting from where i copped the text in input as well as output.

Comment: That's nice! Go for it.

Comment: Show some code for us to help you with. What have you tried so far? From what I read here, I do not understand your problem or what you need help with, flagging to close as unclear.

Comment: want to maintaining same formatting in textarea. suppose if i copied a text from word document like-


text 1
[next para]
text 2

it should shows like that in textarea, not like 

text1 text 2

Comment: that still doesn't explain exactly what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You just need a rich text editor that will solve your problem. Text editors like [Ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) will give you features like text highlighting, text indentation, etc etc.